# Refactoring part of code to a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, refactoring

I have this code:

```
    for (UserDTO usersList:userRepo.getContent()) {
        Set<String> str2 = new HashSet<>();
        for (String authority:usersList.getAuthorities()) {
            if(!authority.equals(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN) && !authority.equals(AuthoritiesConstants.USER)){
                str2.add(authority);
            }
        }
        usersList.getAuthorities().removeAll(str2);
    }
```

it's possible to reduce this to a lambda expression ?

Comment: Well this code doesn't even compile. Also, it's not clear what part you'd want to create a lambda from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `removeIf` as :

```
userRepo.getContent().forEach(usersList -> 
        usersList.getAuthority()
                .removeIf(authority -> 
                        !authority.equals(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN) && !authority.equals(AuthoritiesConstants.USER)));
```